# UWP StreamSocket is only forcibly closed when restarting app

Tags: c#, sockets, win-universal-app

I have a StreamSocket which I dispose of during the shutdown of my UWP application. My client which has the Socket connection still thinks that the connection is alive, even though the application has shut down.

Only when reinitiating the Socket, my client gives a 'Existing connection was forcibly closed' exception.

How can I close a Socket in such a way that the connected PC knows that the connection has closed?

Comment: I have same issue, have you found solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

The client component of the sample creates a TCP socket to make a network connection, uses the socket to send data, and closes the socket. The server component sets up a TCP listener that provides a connected socket for every incoming network connection, uses the socket to receive data from the client, and closes the socket.

You may refer to this GitHub URL:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket

Hope this can help you.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// This is the click handler for the 'CloseSockets' button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Object for which the event was generated.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event's parameters.</param>
    private void CloseSockets_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object outValue;
        if (CoreApplication.Properties.TryGetValue("clientDataWriter", out outValue))
        {
            // Remove the data writer from the list of application properties as we are about to close it.
            CoreApplication.Properties.Remove("clientDataWriter");
            DataWriter dataWriter = (DataWriter)outValue;

            // To reuse the socket with another data writer, the application must detach the stream from the
            // current writer before disposing it. This is added for completeness, as this sample closes the socket
            // in the very next block.
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
            dataWriter.Dispose();
        }

        if (CoreApplication.Properties.TryGetValue("clientSocket", out outValue))
        {
            // Remove the socket from the list of application properties as we are about to close it.
            CoreApplication.Properties.Remove("clientSocket");
            StreamSocket socket = (StreamSocket)outValue;

            // StreamSocket.Close() is exposed through the Dispose() method in C#.
            // The call below explicitly closes the socket.
            socket.Dispose();
        }

        if (CoreApplication.Properties.TryGetValue("listener", out outValue))
        {
            // Remove the listener from the list of application properties as we are about to close it.
            CoreApplication.Properties.Remove("listener");
            StreamSocketListener listener = (StreamSocketListener)outValue;

            // StreamSocketListener.Close() is exposed through the Dispose() method in C#.
            // The call below explicitly closes the socket.
            listener.Dispose();
        }

        CoreApplication.Properties.Remove("connected");
        CoreApplication.Properties.Remove("adapter");
        CoreApplication.Properties.Remove("serverAddress");

        rootPage.NotifyUser("Socket and listener closed", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }
```

Comment: I already call the dispose method in my code, but the other end of the line doesn't seem to notice that the socket was closed. Only when reiniating a connection seems to lead to a connection is forcibly closed exception...